# show hidden child div without changing the size of parent div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following code:

```js
function show() {
  document.getElementById("child").style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
#parent {
  background-color: orange;
  padding: 2em;
}
#child {
  background-color: pink;
  padding: 3em;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent" onmouseover="show()">
  <div id="child">
    Child div
  </div>
</div>
```

When I hover over the parent div, the size of the parent changes. Is there a way to show the child div above the parent div, without changing the size of the parent div?

Comment: With "above" you mean in the z-order, in the position on the screen, or what?

Answer (score 5):

You can use

```
visibility:hidden
```

in place of

```
display:none
```

To show/hide the content and keep the size unchanged. Need to change the script accordingly.

Comment: if  i use **visibility :hidden** my parent div take the size of child div which is not my case ..

Comment: Its obvious, when you showing some additional contents on the page, it will take some space, so you have to reserve the space if you dont want to make any height change. If you want to display it as popup content, use position:absolute instead.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a relative position on your parent and an absolute position on the child elements:

```js
function show()
{
  document.getElementById("child").style.display="block";
}
```

```css
#parent
{
  background-color: orange;
  padding:2em;
  position:relative;
}

#child
{
  background-color: pink;
  padding: 3em;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="parent" onmouseover="show()">
<div id="child">
Child div
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you require http://jsfiddle.net/u74m4x9o/

```
<div id="parent" onmouseover="show()">
  <div id="child">
    Child div
  </div>
</div>


   function show() {
  document.getElementById("child").style.display = "block";
} 



#parent {
  background-color: orange;
  padding: 2em;
}
#child {
  background-color: pink;
  padding: 1em;
  display: none;
  position:absolute;
  top : 1em
}
```